# Add margins in a png file

Tags: flutter, image, dart

I have a generated png file with a barcode, I need to save the file on the device, can I add margins on the sides to the picture so that the barcode is read correctly

Comment: Are you using `RepaintBoundary` to render the image?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this can be using the [screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) package (that takes a screenshot of the child widget and saves it as a .png file) to take a screenshot of the image widget inside a padding widget. Give the padding the value you want to see as a margin in the image.

Another approach can be generating that barcode in .svg format and modifying its code before saving.

Or give [RepaintBoundary](https://youtu.be/cVAGLDuc2xE) a try.